# Error with reading a text file and randomising the words

Tags: python

I am trying to access a text file and randomize the words but keep getting an error.

```
import random

amazement_words = open("amazement_words.txt", "r")
WORDS = (amazement_words)
word = random.choice(amazement_words)
amazement_words.close()
```

Comment: What does the file `amazement_words.txt` look like?

Comment: Post the error you are getting here.

Answer (score 2):

`amazement_words` is not something that you can send to anything in the `random` module. You will need to read the file, split the contents up into a list, and shuffle the list. Also, your program would have no output because you don't print, write to a file, or any other output method. The line `WORDS = (amazement_words)` simply assigns that file handle to a new name (which you don't use) Finally, you can use the `with` construct to close files automatically.

```
import random

with open('amazement_words.txt') as f:
    content = f.read().split()

random.shuffle(content)
print(*content)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're opening a file handle, but never actually reading in the contents:

```
import random
amazement_words = open("amazement_words.txt", "r") # open file
WORDS = amazement_words.read().split()             # read file contents and split on spaces
word = random.choice(WORDS)                        # pick random word
amazement_words.close()
```

And just for fun, here's the one-liner:

```
rand_word = random.choice(open('your_file.txt').read().split())
```